# How to lay twisted Images on top of each other; Python - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am taking pictures of the same object on a turning table from different angles. 
Like this I found matching points on the Image: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography

Now I want to put all the pictures on top of each other and eventually analyse it.
Is it possible to match / overlay these pictures using the previously found matching points?

I was playing around with getAffineTransform / getPerspectiveTransform and warpAffine / warpPerspective but I couldn't really get anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean "image registration"? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584527/ios-opencv-image-registration-alignment

Comment: Is it something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q16lXMIVDbM) you want to achieve? In `cv::Keypoint`, there is a `class_id` member that can be used to identify the source image. Perspective transformation holds only for planar scene or rotational camera motion for generic scene.

Comment: Yes the first links looks like a similar problem. I need to put the pictures on top of each other. Actually I just had an idea. Thanks for your help. I will try!